# Ordered set and natural bijection (combinatorial species)

Tags: algorithm, haskell, complexity-theory, combinatorics

Let `A` some set (eg. `1000, 1001, 1002, ..., 1999`).

Let `lessThan` some order relation function (eg. `(a lessThan b) <-> (a > b)`).

Let `index` a function (with inverse `index'`) mapping a `A` element to naturals.

Example:

```
index a = 2000 - a
index' n = 2000 - n
```

Exists some way to construct `index` (and `index'`) function for all (or some kinds of) `(A, lessThan)` pairs in P (polynomial time)?

Best regards and thank's in advance!

**EDITED**: `A` could be a set by definition (eg. all combinations with repetition of another big subset), then, we can't suppose `A` is completely traversable (in P).

**EDITED**: another non trivial example, let `An` a set (with elements like `(x, y, p)`) whose elements are ordered clockwise into a `n X n` square, like this

```
 1    2    3    4
12   13   14    5
11   16   15    6
10    9    8    7
```

then, we can map each triplet in `An` to `Bn = [1..n^2]` with `O(1)` (a polynomial).

Given one `An` element we can `index` to `Bn` with `O(1)`.
Given one `Bn` element we can `index'` to `An` with `O(1)`.

```
// Square perimeter; square x = 1, 2, 3, ...
Func<int, int, int> perimeter = ( x, n ) => 4 * ( n - 2 * x + 1 ); 

// Given main diagonal coordinates (1, 1), (2, 2), ... return cell number
Func<int, int, int> diagonalPos = ( x, n ) => -4 * x * x + ( 4 * n + 8 ) * x - 4 * n - 3; 

// Given a number, return their square
Func<int, int, int> inSquare = ( z, n ) => (int) Math.Floor(n * 0.5 - 0.5 * Math.Sqrt(n * n - z + 1.0) + 1.0); 

Func<int, int, Point> coords = ( z, n ) => { 
    var s = inSquare(z, n); 
    var l = perimeter(s, n) / 4; // length sub-square edge -1 
    var l2 = l + l; 
    var l3 = l2 + l; 
    var d = diagonalPos(s, n); 
    if( z <= d + l ) 
        return new Point(s + z - d, s); 
    if( z <= d + l2 ) 
        return new Point(s + l, s + z - d - l); 
    if( z <= d + l3 ) 
        return new Point(s + d + l3 - z, s + l); 
    return new Point(s, s + d + l2 + l2 - z); 
};
```

(I have read about "Combinatorial species", ["Ordered construction of combinatorial objects"](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~nachumd/papers/OrderedConstruction.pdf), ["species" haskell package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/species) and others)

Comment: Thank you negative feedback, you are very kind in NOT explaining that I did wrong.

Comment: Is the set finite? Just to double-check, it's countable?

Comment: @Nicholas Wilson, yes, you can suppose `A` is finite and countable (enumerable). But, can construct (ever, in some cases) a `index` function to access elements? (eg. over naturals identity, my example, etc...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding what you want, but in case I'm not:

If `lessThan` defines a total order on the set, you can create the `index` and `index'` functions by

- converting the set to a list (or an array/vector)
- sorting that according to `lessThan`
- construct `index'` as `Data.Map.fromDistinctAscList $ zip [1 .. ] sortedList`
- construct `index` as `Data.Map.fromDistinctAscList $ zip (map NTC sortedList) [1 .. ]`

where `NTC` is a newtype constructor wrapping the type of elements of the set in a newtype whose `Ord` instance is given by `lessThan`.

```
newtype Wrapped = NTC typeOfElements

instance Eq Wrapped where
    (NTC x) /= (NTC y) = x `lessThan` y || y `lessThan` x
-- that can usually be done more efficiently

instance Ord Wrapped where
    (NTC x) <= (NTC y) = not $ y `lessThan` x
```

> **EDITED**: A could be a set by definition (eg. all combinations with repetition of another big subset), then, we can't suppose A is completely traversable (in P).

In that case, unless I'm missing something fundamental, it's impossible in principle, because the `index'` function would provide a complete traversal of the set.

So you can create the `index` and `index'` functions in polynomial time if and only if the set is traversable in polynomial time.

Comment: Your haskell construction is very nice, but (my fault, excuse me, I have edited question) `A` could be not traversable in P. My example construct `index` (and `index'`) without traverse `A`. I have included #Haskell tag by `species` package. Thank you anyway!

Comment: `index'` would provide a traversal. So you can construct it in polynomial time if and only if `A` is traversable in polynomial time.

Comment: forgive my poor explanation, I have added a non trivial example, in some cases we can construct `index/index'` without traverse set. (In general) in what cases we can construct these?